# Dynamically adding image

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am building an Angular app. I need to add different images to each button.

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let Items of myItems">
    <button class="close-image"><img src="../../assets/img/flower.png">
        <span>         
        </span> 
    </button>
</div>
```

From above code I am creating buttons depend on response (example: four buttons), and all buttons contain same image. How should I add different images to each of these `ngFor` buttons?

Comment: save image paths in array in your .ts file. then use ngfor

Comment: have you created model for `myItems`, if so. You can add image field to that modal. while getting `myItems` value, you can assign image value to that key. So in markup you can get `image`

Comment: Same like @Explosion Pills' answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the input binding `[src]` to specify the source from properties. Let's assume that `Items` has an `imgSrc` property:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of myItems">
  <button class="close-image"><img [src]="item.imgSrc">
    <span>{{item.text}}</span> 
  </button>
</div>
```

You can also concatenate strings in this binding if you need to specify the path

```
[src]="'../../assets/img/' + item.imgSrc"
```

This assumes that `myItems` looks something like this (whether it comes from a server or is hard coded):

```
myItems = [
  { imgSrc: 'flower.png', text: 'Flower' },
  { imgSrc: 'flower2.png', text: 'Flower2' },
];
```

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<img *ngFor="let image of images" [src]="image">
```

component

```
images = [
  'path/to/image/1',
  'path/to/image/2',
  'path/to/image/3',
];
```